# Does Haskell's 'evaluate' reduce to normal or WHNF?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, denotational-semantics

I understand ([I think](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33055462/656912)) that Haskell's `seq`, will (generally) [reduce](https://hackhands.com/lazy-evaluation-works-haskell/) its first argument to [WHNF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6889335/656912), and see this behavior as expected in GHCi:

```
λ> let x = (trace "foo" Foo (trace "bar" Bar 100)) in seq x 0
foo
0
```

However, though the [documentation for `evaluate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:evaluate) says that it also reduces its argument to WHNF, it looks like it actually fully reduces its argument to normal form:

```
λ> let x = (trace "foo" Foo (trace "bar" Bar 100)) in evaluate x
foo
Foo bar
(Bar 100)
```

I can confirm this (apparent) discrepancy with

```
λ> let y = (trace "foo" Foo (trace "bar" Bar 100))
λ> seq y 0
foo
0
λ> :sprint y
y = <Foo> _
```

and

```
λ> let z = (trace "foo" Foo (trace "bar" Bar 100))
λ> evaluate z
foo
Foo bar
(Bar 100)
λ> :sprint z
z = <Foo> (<Bar> 100)
```

If the documentation for `evaluate` is correct, shouldn't the behavior of `seq` and `evaluate` be the same? What am I missing here (as a Haskell beginner)?

Comment: By the way, there's no way at all to polymorphically (without a type class) evaluate a value beyond WHNF.

Comment: @ReidBarton: Can you explain that a bit further (or is it [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33070412/656912))?

Comment: It's not the same as in that link, it's just that without a type class, you have no way to get the information about how to access the subparts of a value of unknown type. (Hm, no high-level way, anyway - maybe there's some hideously unsafe way using the garbage collector's data)

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: Is that relevant here, to `x`, for example?

Comment: Not much, since clearly you *do* know `x`'s precise type.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: Good, I was confused about why it had been brought up in this context.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Presumably it had been brought up as a general statement of which one specialization is that `evaluate` -- which accepts a fully polymorphic argument -- does not evaluate a value beyond WHNF.

Comment: Whereas [NFData](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.4.1.2/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html#t:NFData) enables you to fully evaluate a value to normal form (as long as the instance follows the rules).

Comment: Right, what @DanielWagner said. It's an answer to the question in the title. Not just `evaluate`, but *any* function of the same type `a -> IO a` can evaluate its argument no further than to WHNF.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you are missing is that GHCi also *prints* the result of IO actions (if they can be shown and are not `()`), which *does* cause it to evaluate to normal form.  Try instead:

```
λ> let x = (trace "foo" Foo (trace "bar" Bar 100)) in evaluate x >> return ()
foo
```

Comment: Perfect! As soon as I posted I wondered about this, but I'm still vague enough on IO actions and how they work (especially when they are "embedded" as they are in interactions with GHCi) that I couldn't quite nail it down.